# Number theory - rational number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Are there any $x, y$ that fit in below

$\sqrt{4y^2-3x^2}$ such that an rational number is yielded.

Appreciate if explanation is given.

Comment: I may be misreading the question, but by setting $x=y=1$ we get $\sqrt{1}$ which is clearly rational

Comment: $\sqrt{0}$ is also rational.

Comment: Also $x=0$ and $y$ rational does it...

Comment: Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are intended to be integers, the expression will be rational only if it's also integral, and there are well-known parameterizations of all the rational solutions to equations like $ax^2+by^2=z^2$.

Comment: would you please direct me to source of the parameterizations aforesaid mentioned, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want $4y^2-3x^2=n^2 \iff (2y-n)(2y+n) = 3x^2$

So for e.g. we can set $2y-n = 3, 2y+n = x^2 \implies y= \dfrac{x^2+3}4, n = \dfrac{x^2-3}2$ and both will be integer if $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.  Thus $x = 2k+1, y = k^2+k+1$ should work for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and we find
$$4y^2-3x^2 = 4(k^2+k+1)^2-3(2k+1)^2 = (2k^2+2k-1)^2$$
giving you at least one infinite family of solutions. You could try other ways of factoring $3x^2$ if you need to find other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We can find infinitely many solutions by considering the Pell equation $y^2-3s^2=1$.

We look for perfect squares $4y^2-3x^2$, where $x$ is even, say $2s$. Then we want $4y^2-12s^2$ to be a perfect square, say $(2t)^2$. So we want to solve the Diophantine equation $y^2-3s^2=t^2$.

There are already infinitely many solutions with $t=1$. For $(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=1$.  Thus $(2+\sqrt{3})^n(2-\sqrt{3})^n=1$.

But $(2+\sqrt{3})^n=y_n+s_n\sqrt{3}$ for integers $y_n$, $s_n$. It follows that $y_n^2-3s_n^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to try different integers. Some quick ones we could try are $x = 0, y = 1$, and $x = y = 1$.

For $x = 0, y = 1: \sqrt{4-0} = \sqrt{4} = 2$ and for $x = y = 1: \sqrt{4 - 3} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.

Comment: how about non- trivial x y and x and y >1?

Comment: By non-trivial do you mean more complex sets of integers, or do you mean rationals, etc.?

Comment: more complex set of integers please

Answer (score 0):

You can view $4x^2-3y^2=1=(2x)^2-3y^2$ as a form of [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_equation).  All solutions of this will do what you want, though there will be more solutions to your problem.  As others have commented $x_1=1,y_1=1$ is a solution.  Given $(x_n,y_n)$ is a solution,  $x_{n+1}=7x_n+6y_n,y_{n+1}=8x_n+7y_n$ will be another solution.  The next few are $(13,15),(181,209),(2521,2911)$  You can find solutions to equations of this sort (with explanations if you want) at [Dario Alpern's site](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM)